# Custom variable in dynamic button creation in PayPal

Tags: php, paypal

Currently in PayPal you can dynamically generate PayPal Buttons using the following

[BMCreateButton](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/api/button-manager/BMCreateButton_API_Operation_NVP/)

Is their a way to add a variable called `custom` to the button as It's not documented within the API?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use L_BUTTONVARn option.
Like this :

```
array(
    'L_BUTTONVAR1' => 'custom=price=1.00&customvar=value&othervar=othervalue'
);
```

It will go directly to custom vars.